# Why eager loading HABTM associations in Rails 5 is not working with bullet gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, include, associations, query-optimization, has-and-belongs-to-many

**Hi, here are my relations in the app**

```
class SourcedContact < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :contact
end

class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :companies, join_table: 'companies_contacts'
  has_and_belongs_to_many :email_addresses, join_table: 'contacts_email_addresses'
  has_and_belongs_to_many :phone_numbers, join_table: 'contacts_phone_numbers'
  has_and_belongs_to_many :addresses, join_table: 'contacts_addresses'
end
```

And I am trying to eager load associations when SourcedContact is loaded.
And my Query is as below and working also.

```
SourcedContact.includes(contact: [:contacts_companies,:companies, :contacts_email_addresses,:email_addresses, :contacts_phone_numbers,:phone_numbers])
```

**My Question is why it is not working as**

```
SourcedContact.includes(contact: [:companies,:email_addresses,:phone_numbers])
```

Kindly clarify my doubts.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Why should it work like that in your opinion?

Comment: @MarekLipka, Because my model names are company, email_address, phone_numbers but not contacts_companies, contacts_email_addresses, contacts_phone_numbers.

Comment: @kotub It should be `SourcedContact.includes(contact: [:companies,:email_addresses,:phone_numbers)`

Comment: @MarekLipka I have updated.. that is just typo. sorry for that.

Comment: @kotub Can you please all add log what you get when you hit this query ?

Comment: `Bullet::Notification::UnoptimizedQueryError:         Bullet::Notification::UnoptimizedQueryError:
        POST /v1/contact.json
        USE eager loading detected
          Contact => [:contacts_companies]
          Add to your finder: :includes => [:contacts_companies]`

I am using bullet gem to identify N+1 Queries. 

`SourcedContact.includes(contact: [:companies,:email_addresses,:phone_numbers)`

The query is working fine without bullet gem. But with bullet gem the above is the error.

Comment: @kotub Are you using Active model Serializer?

Comment: @Vishal I am using grape entity(which are sort of serialisers) for exposing response.

Comment: @kotub I never used grape entity but I am sure its issue of your response, maybe in your response you are not using eager loading, that's why it generates n + 1, the above query is perfect, you just need to eager load in your response.

Comment: @Vishal For the Query with bullet gem is throwing Unoptimised query error

`SourcedContact.includes(contact: [:companies,:email_addresses,:phone_numbers)`

And so I have modified  and no issues with bullet.

`SourcedContact.includes(contact: [:contacts_companies,:companies, :contacts_email_addresses,:email_addresses, :contacts_phone_numbers,:phone_numbers])`

But not not all sure, why it should be this way..

Comment: @kotub I don't understand what you are trying to say? Does your issue resolve?

Comment: Without bullet gem the below query is eager loading properly.
`SourcedContact.includes(contact: [:companies,:email_addresses,:phone_numbers)`
   But with bullet gem the same query is throwing error.

Comment: Why are you using join_table? Does your table name is different? If your table name is contacts_companies then maybe you don't need to specify join table

Comment: @Vishal I have retried without specifying the join tables, but still my issue continuing. I just thought join tables wont cause any issue and they are.